# Trouble with indexes in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice-writer

When I set indexes in LO Writer, by default I got 1 column, which looks great:
[image]

but when I set 2 columns, I got completely mess (I didn't change any other option except that I set 2 columns):
[image]

What is wrong?

I'm using:
Ubuntu 13.10
LibreOffice 4.1.3.2

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the spacing between the columns? Go to `Edit Index/Table` -> `Columns` and adjust the `Spacing`.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same.

Comment: So you went through all the settings available for Index/Columns and couldn't see any changes? Try switching back to single column and then back to 2. Also, try removing the Index and re-adding it. I have tested the spacing on LO version 4.1.5.3 on Fedora and it works fine. Try upgrading.

Comment: Maybe the `Index[1/2/3]` styles or the `Default Style` are modified? The Index styles are based on the Default Style. It seems the paragraph styles have an additional negative "after"-indentation, making the content running into the spacing / border area.

Comment: slybloty, I did that all, and a did upgrade to v4.2.2.1 and nothing happens.

Comment: tohuwawohu, you were right. I made some changes to Default style. I copied the whole text in new document and everything works fine.